# Playing incoming audio stream on different pages

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-8.1

I am building some Shared Project which is connected with Playing incoming internet radio stream.
Currently I ve got a problem with Playing this stream on different pages.
I made some background task and it works fine I can easily minimize my app but when I am moving to different page where the user will read the RSS feed (Frame.Navigate some DataContext which contains the RSS),the Media Element stop playing.

I try to find some solution myself, but I didn't find any which will be the best for my.

Thank you for your help

```
 public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    SystemMediaTransportControls systemControls = SystemMediaTransportControls.GetForCurrentView();

    FeedDataSource feedDataSource = (FeedDataSource)App.Current.Resources["feedDataSource"];
    FeedData nFeedData = new FeedData();

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        InitializeTransportControls();


    }

    private void Media_CurrentStateChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (Media.CurrentState)
        {
            case MediaElementState.Closed:
                systemControls.PlaybackStatus = MediaPlaybackStatus.Closed;
                break;
            case MediaElementState.Paused:
                systemControls.PlaybackStatus = MediaPlaybackStatus.Paused;
                break;
            case MediaElementState.Playing:
                systemControls.PlaybackStatus = MediaPlaybackStatus.Playing;
                break;
            case MediaElementState.Stopped:
                systemControls.PlaybackStatus = MediaPlaybackStatus.Stopped;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    } 


    private async void PlayButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {


            Media.Play();

        });

    }



    private async void StopButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {


            Media.Stop();

        });
    }

    private async void PauseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {


            Media.Pause();

        });
    }

    private void VolumeSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Media.Volume = e.NewValue;

    }
    void InitializeTransportControls()
    {
        // Windows.Media 

        systemControls.ButtonPressed += systemControls_ButtonPressed;

        systemControls.IsPlayEnabled = true;
        systemControls.IsPauseEnabled = true;
    }
    // Handle ButtonPressed for systemControls 
    void systemControls_ButtonPressed(SystemMediaTransportControls sender, SystemMediaTransportControlsButtonPressedEventArgs args)
    {
        switch (args.Button)
        {
            case SystemMediaTransportControlsButton.Pause:
                Media.Play();
                break;
            case SystemMediaTransportControlsButton.Play:
                Media.Pause();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }


    protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {


        if (feedDataSource != null)
        {
            if (feedDataSource.Feeds.Count == 0)
            {
                await feedDataSource.GetFeedsAsync();
            }

            MenuSection.DataContext = feedDataSource.Feeds;

        }

    }
    private void ItemListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {



    }

    private void Contetnview_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Contetnview_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {


       var x
            = ((GridView)sender).SelectedItem;

       var z = ((Grid)x).Tag.ToString();




        switch (z)
        {
            case "1":
                Frame.Navigate(typeof(ReadNewsPage), feedDataSource.Feeds[0]);

                break;
            case "2":
                Frame.Navigate(typeof(ReadNewsPage), feedDataSource.Feeds[3]);
                break;
            case "3":
                Frame.Navigate(typeof(ReadNewsPage), feedDataSource.Feeds[2]);
                break;
            case "4":
                Frame.Navigate(typeof(ReadNewsPage), feedDataSource.Feeds[1]);
                break;


        }
    }

}

 <Grid x:Name="ThisGris" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <MediaElement x:Name="Media" Source="http://5.201.13.191:80/live" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="206" Margin="107,372,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="213" AudioCategory="BackgroundCapableMedia" AutoPlay="False" CurrentStateChanged="Media_CurrentStateChanged"/>
    <Hub x:Name="MainHubPage" Header="" Margin="0,3,0,-3" >

        <Hub.Background>
            <ImageBrush  />
        </Hub.Background>
        <HubSection Header="Radio" Width="402"  IsHeaderInteractive="True">

            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Width="429" Height="565" d:IsLocked="True">
                    <Button x:Name="PlayButton" Content="Play" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="118,352,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="58" Width="83" Click="PlayButton_Click"  d:IsLocked="True"/>
                    <Button x:Name="StopButton" Content="Stop" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="7,352,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="58" Click="StopButton_Click" d:IsLocked="True"/>
                    <Button x:Name="PauseButton" Content="Pause" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="236,352,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="58" Click="PauseButton_Click" d:IsLocked="True"/>
                    <Slider x:Name="VolumeSlider" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="53,295,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="267"  Minimum="0" Value="50" Maximum="100" ValueChanged="VolumeSlider_ValueChanged" d:IsLocked="True"/>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,129,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="20" Text="Na antenie :" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="40" Width="135" d:IsLocked="True"/>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,174,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="20" Text="Gramy :" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="42" Width="135" d:IsLocked="True"/>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,216,0,0" FontSize="20" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Wkrótce : " VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="42" Width="118" d:IsLocked="True"/>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="150,216,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="42" Width="269" d:IsLocked="True"/>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="150,129,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="269" d:IsLocked="True"/>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="150,174,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="42" Width="293" d:IsLocked="True"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
        <HubSection x:Name="MenuSection" Width="606"  IsHeaderInteractive="True">
            <DataTemplate>
                <GridView x:Name="Contetnview"                             
                           DataContext="{Binding}"
                          Height="519" Width="606" SelectionChanged="Contetnview_SelectionChanged"  >
                    <Grid x:Name="Dowiadomosci" Height="135" Width="161" Tag="1" DataContext="{Binding }">
                        <TextBlock Text="Wiadomości"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid x:Name="Dodupy" Height="135" Width="161" Tag="2" DataContext="{Binding Path=Feeds[0]}" >
                        <TextBlock Text="Muzyka"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid Height="135" Width="161" Tag="3" DataContext="{Binding Path=Feeds[0]}">
                        <TextBlock Text="Kultura"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid Height="135" Width="161"  Tag="4" DataContext="{Binding Source=feedDataSource, Path=Feeds[0]}">
                        <TextBlock Text="Sport"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid Height="135" Width="161" Tag="5">
                        <TextBlock Text="O nas"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid Height="135" Width="161" Tag="6">
                        <TextBlock Text="Audycja Autorskie"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid Height="135" Width="161" Tag="7">
                        <TextBlock Text="Ekipa"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid Height="135" Width="161" >
                        <TextBlock Text="Ramówka"/>
                    </Grid>
                </GridView>                                  
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
        <HubSection x:Name="Schedule" Width="606" Header="Ramówka"  IsHeaderInteractive="True" DataContext="{Binding Source=feedDataSource, Path=Feeds[0]}">
            <DataTemplate>
                <GridView x:Name="ScheduleContent"  Height="519" Width="606" ItemClick="Contetnview_ItemClick">

                    <Grid Height="135" Width="161" >
                        <TextBlock Text="Ramówka"></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
                </GridView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
        <HubSection x:Name="Team" Width="606" Header="Ekipa"  IsHeaderInteractive="True" DataContext="{Binding Source=feedDataSource, Path=Feeds[0]}">
            <DataTemplate>
                <GridView x:Name="TeamContent"  Height="519" Width="606" ItemClick="Contetnview_ItemClick">
                    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Height="135" Width="161" >
                                <Image>

                                </Image>
                            </Grid>

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                </GridView>

            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
        <HubSection x:Name="AuthorShow" Width="606" Header="Audycje Autorskie"  IsHeaderInteractive="True" DataContext="{Binding Source=feedDataSource, Path=Feeds[0]}">
            <DataTemplate>
                <GridView x:Name="AuthorShowContent"  Height="519" Width="606" ItemClick="Contetnview_ItemClick">

                    <Grid Height="135" Width="161" >
                        <Image>

                        </Image>
                    </Grid>
                </GridView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>          
        <HubSection x:Name="AboutUs" Width="606" Header="O nas"  IsHeaderInteractive="True" DataContext="{Binding Source=feedDataSource, Path=Feeds[0]}">
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid x:Name="AboutUSContent"  Height="519" Width="606" >
                    <TextBlock Text="TutajONAS"></TextBlock>
                </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
      </HubSection>
    </Hub>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Can you share code, so folks can help easier?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that reason the music stops is because you are creating the stream in a page, and then moving away from the page which is causing everything you just allocated to go away.

I would recommend trying to create/play your media player object in the App.xaml.cs file.
This should live across page calls.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2014/04/24/frame-of-reference-keeping-the-music-playing-across-pages.aspx Here I found some solution :) but thanks for your help. Sorry that I answer late but I was busy last time :)